# React Native TextInput value not updating

Tags: react-native, rendering, react-native-textinput, cancel-button

I have a TextInput field that when a user is editing, they have the option to cancel. The goal is to revert the TextInput value back to the original value before the user started editing, however, even though the previous value is stored and the screen is re-rendering, the text on the screen stays however the user left it. I'm assuming I'm just misunderstanding how the TextInput component works.

This is the input in question:

```
<TextInput
   style={styles.workoutheader}
   editable={editableWorkout == workout.id}
   onChangeText={(workoutName) => setWorkoutName(workoutName)}
>
{workout.name}
</TextInput>
```

and this is the cancel button:

```
<TouchableOpacity
 style={styles.workoutheadericon}
 onPress={() => {
    console.log('Reverting to: ' + prevWorkoutName, prevWorkoutType, prevWorkoutWeight, prevWorkoutReps);
    setWorkoutName(prevWorkoutName);
    setWorkoutType(prevWorkoutType);
    setWorkoutWeight(prevWorkoutWeight);
    setWorkoutReps(prevWorkoutReps);
    setEditableWorkout('');
    setIsEditing(!isEditing);
    setActionCounter(actionCounter + 1);
 }}
>
```

`{workout.name}` is coming from a firestore database, but I don't think that's related.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the variable `workout` gets updated when you call `setWorkoutName`, try replacing `{workout.name}` with `workoutName` or whatever variable name you used where you declared your `useState` function that created the `setWorkoutName` setter function, e.g.

```js
const [workoutName, setWorkoutName] = useState(workout.name)

return (
<TextInput
   style={styles.workoutheader}
   editable={editableWorkout == workout.id}
   onChangeText={(workoutName) => setWorkoutName(workoutName)}
>
{/* should be `workoutName` here, not `workout.name` */ workoutName}
</TextInput>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the only issue is that I don't have access to the workout object outside of the map I'm in here: 
{workouts && workouts.map((workout, key) => {
//text input here
}}

Comment: Oh, then you can just make `workout.name` the default value if the `workoutName` is null and set it to null where you have the `useState` call: `const [workoutName, setWorkoutName] = useState(null)` ... `<TextInput ...>{workoutName === null ? workout.name : workoutName }</TextInput>`

Comment: That makes sense and is almost working, but then how do I get each `workoutName` to be different when `workoutName` gets set. That's making every workout then get set to the same value? The `onChangeText={(workoutName) => setWorkoutName(workoutName)}` is doing this I believe.

Comment: So you could either use an object to map from workout IDs (or something similar) to the workout name, or you could render a custom component for each workout in your `workouts.map()` (instead of just a TextInput, you could have a component with its own workoutName state and everything)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I needed to target the workout being edited with
`editableWorkout == workout.id ? workoutName : workout.name}` which let me differentiate between the workouts using Leon Si's answer.